# ANTLR grammar discrepancy

Tags: antlr, antlr4

```
grammar g;
// %doc(file = "idocfile.yml")

prog: (decl | expr)+
    ;
decl: VAR '=' '"' STR '"'
    |'%doc' '(' VAR '=' '"' STR '"' ')'
    |'%quiz' '(' VAR '=' '"' STR '"' ')' .*? '%quiz'
    ;
expr:expr '*' expr
    |expr '+' expr
    |expr '-' expr
    |expr '=' expr
    |DOC
    |STR
    ;

// tokens
VAR: [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ ;
STR: [a-zA-Z.]*;
WS: [ \t\n]+ -> skip;
```

Testing example:

```
%doc(file = "idocfile.yml")
%quiz(title= "assembler quiz")
test
%quiz
```

For this testing this example with the above grammar the antlr shows error:

```bash
line 2:14 mismatched input 'assembler' expecting STR
line 2:24 mismatched input 'quiz' expecting '='
line 2:28 missing '=' at '"'
line 2:29 mismatched input ')' expecting STR
line 2:36 mismatched input '%quiz' expecting '='
line 4:0 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting '('
```

Comment: Your STR token doesn't include spaces, so `"assembler quiz"` is not a valid STR.

Comment: Note that the way you've defined it, `"x"` also wouldn't work because `x` is a `VAR`, not a `STR`. You should really have a single token for the entire string literal, including the quotes, instead of having the quotes and the contents each being their own tokens.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments: a `STR` should include the quotes in the lexer rule, not in a parser rule. As you have it now:

```
VAR: [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ ;
STR: [a-zA-Z.]*;
```

the input `abc` will always become a `VAR`, even when you're doing `'"' STR '"'` in your parser. The lexer does not "listen" to what the parser needs.

Do something like this instead:

```
STR: '"' ~["\r\n]* '"';
```

(assuming your strings cannot contain line breaks)

And if escaped quotes are to be supported, do:

```
STR: '"' ( ~["\r\n] | '\\' [\\"] )* '"';
```

And remove the quotes from your parser rule:

```
decl: VAR '=' STR
    |'%doc' '(' VAR '=' STR ')'
    |'%quiz' '(' VAR '=' STR ')' .*? '%quiz'
    ;
```

And be aware that in a parser rule `.*` does not match "zero or more characters" (like it does in a lexer rule), but means "zero or more tokens".